# Unique SPID for each stored procedure execution

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, connection-pooling, asp.net-web-api2, spid

I am building an angularjs .net application with WebApi2 and SQL Server 2008.When page loads, it sends multiple ajax calls to WebApi. WebApi then in turn passes on these calls to Sql server, but when I look into sql profiler, all calls to db are executed with same SPID,which I believe is a sequential execution rather than parallel execution of stored procs. 
          Even after having looking at the network monitor tab on firefox browser, all these calls return one after another and not at the same time.This might create bottleneck in the system , as angular sends parallel request to webapi but sql server is executing each request sequentially rather than parallel.
I have used Data Access Application Block v6.0 and have put Connection and Command objects under "Using" scope. Still it fires all my storedproc with same SPID. Is there anything which I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with those web technologies, but have one possible idea... are you connection pooling?  A single SPID means a single connection to the SQL Server.  If your connection pool has multiple connections available, you should be grabbing a new connection for each simultaneous execution.  How many connections are available to your application?

Comment: I believe .NET connection pools by default and will only create new connections when needed. If the queries were lightweight it's possible you're only seeing the one SPID because that is all that was needed - i.e each query returned before the next one was even ready. Are you 100% sure the requests were received and the queries dispatched from .NET in parallel?

Comment: Connection pooling is by default as provided.I haven't added any extra parameter to turn it ON or OFF in my connection string. But, can we say single SPID means stored procs are still getting executed parallel rather than sequential?